# How to include the kernel configuration to my meta-layer and into the build?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am using cl-som-imx7 board,  using gatesgarth branch to setup the yocto env.
I have changed the kernel configurations by

1. Executing the command
   `bitbake -c memuconfig virtual/kernel`
2. Rename the `.config` to `defconfig`

I don't have any luck in including those changes inside my build. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following section of the Yocto Manual illustrates how to do that:
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html#changing-the-configuration

You basically need to rename this `.config` file to `defconfig` and add it with your kernel recipe to be as follows

```
linux_x.x.bb  
linux  
|  
|_ defconfig
```

and add the following lines to your recipe:

```
 # This to add the package name directory to search paths (i.e. The recipe name which is linux in this example) 
 FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
 SRC_URI += "file://defconfig"
```